# How to check if an image is loaded with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a basic image element on my page. I am capturing it's load event to log a message to my console.

```
$("#myImg").on('load', function() {
    console.log("Loaded");
});
```

The above code works perfectly fine, unless the image that is being loaded already exists within the users cache, in that case the message is not loaded at all.

Is there an event such as `loaded` to check if the image is already loaded?

Comment: Use `imageObj.complete` before `load`

Answer (score 15):

> Check `imageObj.complete` before `load` event. `complete` is image object property.

[**HTMLImageElement.complete**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement#Properties) : *Returns a Boolean that is true if the browser has finished fetching the image, whether successful or not. It also shows true, if the image has no `src` value.*

```js
var elem = $("#myImg");

if (!elem.prop('complete')) {
  console.log("Waiting to be loaded!");
  elem.on('load', function() {
    console.log("Loaded!");
    console.log(this.complete);
  });
} else {
  console.log("Already loaded!");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src='http://www.wired.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/google-logo.jpg' id='myImg'>
```

Comment: `elem.prop('complete')` returns `true` even with an image that is not cached

Comment: Justify your statement..

Comment: Works like a charm, when you need to wait until all images loaded in your slider! Best answer that Google gave to me. Thanks @Rayon!

Answer (score 0):

You can append a random number as a version to the image. So every time it will load the image and not take it from cache on page reload.

```
var randNum = Math.random();
var imageSource= "../include/images/image.png?v="+randNum ;
```

Assign imageSource to the src attribute of your img tag.